# Simple Facebook "like" Form

Tags: javascript, facebook, forms, facebook-graph-api

I'm in kind of a unique situation where I need to generate new "likes" on a Facebook page, but I need to be able to track the names of the people who like the page through my recommendation.  My thought is to create a "form" of sorts that I can share the link to, and the form would have a single button on it.  This button, when clicked, would do 2 things:

1) "Like" the Facebook page in question on their behalf

2) Gather the name data (from Facebook) of the person who liked the page and store that name in a list that only I can access.

That's it.

I'd love it if the list could be storage/generated in Google docs somehow.  **Also, please note that this is not my Facebook page or a page that I control in any way.**  Now, I realize that there is a less complicated solution to this, which is to simply embed the "Like" button and have a form that asks people to fill out their name and submit.  However, it is important that the name on Facebook matches with the name I receive.  Is it possible to add new code to the "like" button code from Facebook that mines the name data instead of creating a whole new process?

Please share your thoughts on how this might be accomplished or if there as a better solution.

Comment: I believe Facebook disallows this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to like a page via the Graph API. Also, Facebook doesn't allow this via its platform policies.